# Drawing a custom button with hot or pressed state

Tags: c#, winforms, button, custom-button

I've created a custom button control. Basically one button-rectangle, but with two areas inside the rectangle that have a different behavior. For that reason I want to draw the hot and pressed state ONLY for the specific areas, not the hole button.

My current approach is drawing the basic-button using `ButtonRenderer.DrawButton(...)` with an emtpy text, draw the hot or pressed state if required and finally drawing the text. So far so good, but how do I get the (gradient) colors for the hot/pressed state?

I've tried `SystemColors`, `KnownColors` and `VisualStyleRenderer.GetColor(ColorProperty.XYZ)` but none of them seems to match? How can I read those colors from the host system?

**EDIT:**
Sample picture below:

[image]

I want the colors of both the *hot* and the *pressed* button-state - (light) blue in case of this win7 screenshot. If you zoom in you can see that a slight color gradient in both the upper and the lower half is used.

The last button shows what I want to accomplish.

Sure, I could extract the colors from the screenshots and hardcode them or use images like suggested, but that would work only for this specific system, wouldn't it?

Comment: have you thought about making an independent user control? that will be  rich in features!

Comment: @Amit what would be the benefit inheriting from `UserControl` instead of `Button`? And how would that solve my color problem?

Comment: you can have multiple layer of background colors (images) as you can add multiple container. that way you can have that effect of hot key on click or other action. making custom control is always tricky but sometimes it gives the best result

Comment: What do you mean by gradient colors? Can you elaborate more and add some description and pictures about desired behavior?

Comment: @RezaAghaei example and more explanation added

Comment: [`ButtonRenderer.DrawButton()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ButtonRenderer.cs,8d8bea73b4eb0182) calls [visualStyleRenderer.DrawBackground](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ButtonRenderer.cs,95). You can see that the class [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/VisualStyles/VisualStyleRenderer.cs,271) uses the current Theme to read the button state color, referencing the Part and Bounds of the control to paint.

Comment: See also this SO answer: [How do I draw a button with a nonstandard BackColor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296155/how-do-i-draw-a-button-with-a-nonstandard-backcolor) which references  [ButtonStandardAdapter](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ButtonInternal/ButtonStandardAdapter.cs,b8bb1ecc1e29e447,references)  [`PaintThemedButtonBackground()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ButtonInternal/ButtonStandardAdapter.cs,60) method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers, Jimi.

According to the accepted answer of your linked SO-question I checked `ButtonBaseAdapter` and `ButtonStandardAdapter`. As you also mentioned, `ButtonRenderer.DrawButton` calls `VisualStyleRenderer.DrawBackground` which calls the native API `UxTheme.DrawThemedBackground` to draw the button - the color determination happens inside.
This native API call also draws the button-border and thats the reason why I can't use it.

But I was able to solve my Problem, an unusual way, but it works.

I render both relevant states (hot and pressed) to a bitmap and extract the colors using `.GetPixel`. In `OnPaint` I create `LinearGradientBrush`-instances from the extracted colors and draw the hot/pressed effect over the specific areas of the normal button.

*It's **not** the exact same behavior like a normal button (for both states the border color also changes), but I think it would look really strange if I change the border color only for a part of the button (where the hot/pressed effect is displayed) to match the normal button behavior...*

<s>If no other answers or solutions come up I'll mark this post in a few days as an answer...</s>